# How to detect when virtual keyboar of a SearchView is dismissed

Tags: android, android-virtual-keyboard

I wanna call mSearchView.clearFocus() when virtual keyboard is dismissed, how to do that?

My problem is once the SearchView gets focused, it keeps focused, so if I dismissed the virtual keyboard using back button, and I opened an AlertDialog - for example - the virtual keyboard pops up again once I close the AlertDialog as the search view still has the focus, as if it regains focus.

for the SearchView I used:

```
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:focusable="false"
```

for the activity holds the SearchView I use:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan"
```

even if I changed it to the following I get the same problem

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```

**Eidt 1:**

changing

```
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
```

to be

```
    android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
```

doesn't solve the problem, I get the same result.

**Edit 2:**

I tried the approach of creating a custom SearchView and to override onKeyPreIme and call clearFocus(), but onKeyPreIme doesn't get called.

```
public class ModifiedSearchView extends SearchView {
    public ModifiedSearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme (int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            clearFocus();
            return false;
        }

        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);

    }
}
```

Comment: you are using it with `menu.xml`?

Comment: No, I have the SearchView inside a LinearLayout that holds other views

Comment: My activity is derived from AppCompatActivity

Comment: any update for this jack?

Answer (score 0):

To hide keyboard use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and then in you `onBackPressed()`

```
if (searchView != null) {
searchView.setQuery("", false);
searchView.clearFocus();
rootView.requestFocus();
```

}

while `rootView` is

```
rootView = findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
```

Comment: Thanks, it delivers the same result and worst, where I want SearchView to be focused when the activity starts (but without showing the keyboard), which is android:iconifiedByDefault="false" fulfills

Comment: we usually set `searchView` to the toolbar as the menue_options , and have more control over showing and hiding of it.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to hide the keyboard manually, I just want to force it to loose focus - to avoid reopening the keyboard - when the user close it using back key

Comment: i would suggest you use it as the options_menu in the toolbar , you will have the exact output, i am using it in the same way.

Comment: Thanks, but per design it's not possible to have it in the toolbar, as there's no toolbar, it's a full screen activity.

Comment: Thanks but onBackPressed() doesn't get called for the first time - when the keyboard gets disappeared, it gets called when I press the back button again after it's hidden

Answer (score 0):

I have tried adding a searchview to a linerlayout and i do not have the same problem like you. But if you want to track virtual keyboard hide event use the following code in onCreate()

```
mLLWrapper.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Rect r = new Rect();
                mLLWrapper.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                int heightDiff = mLLWrapper.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
                if (heightDiff > 300) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably
                    // keyboard visible
                } else {
                    // keyboard in not visible
                }
            }
        });
```

`mLLWrapper` is root LinearLayout view of activity

Once the keyboard is dismissed call clear focus. That might help. If not update your question with more code which will be easy for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
internal class ProductSearchView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : SearchView(context, attrs) {

    override fun dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
       return false
    }
}
```